# Text area transposition

Tags: javascript, arrays, transpose

I am a beginner and I've found some useful examples for what I want to do.  The problem is the examples that I've found don't have enough comments for me to understand what is going on.  So, I hope someone can help me implement the code I've found into the code that I already have.  I'm making a text manipulation area to use to play with cipher text.  It's all being done inside a single HTML text area.  I've got a functions called, `"function G_Group(size, count)"`, that breaks the text into rows and columns of choice and it is working great.  The next tool that I want to add will transpose this matrix from (x,y) to (y,x). Because I have the "function G-Group" function, I don't believe I need to slice anything.  I found a bit of JavaScript transposition code at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition#JavaScript  but I don't know how to change the values to add it to what I've got already.

Function G_Group(size, count) is called like this.

```
<input type= button value="Grouping" onclick = "return G_Group(0, 0)" title="grouping" />
```

And here is the how i break text up into rows and columns:

```
function G_Group(size, count)
{
   if (size <= 0)
   {
      size = document.encoder.group_size.value;
      if (size <= 0)                 
      {
         alert('Invalid group size'); 
     return false;
      }
   }
   if (count <= 0)
   {
      count = document.encoder.group_count.value;
      if (count <= 0)             
      {
         alert('Invalid group count');
     return false;
      }
   }

   var t = document.encoder.text.value;
   var o = '', groups = 0;
   t = Tr(t, " \r\n\t");
   while (t.length > 0)
   {
      if (o.length > 0)
      {
         o += ' ';
      }
      if (groups >= count)
      {
         o += "\n";
     groups = 0;
      }
      groups ++;
      o += t.slice(0, size);
      t = t.slice(size, t.length);
   }
   document.encoder.text.value = o;
   return false;
}
```

And this is the code that I want modify to transpose the array.

```
function Matrix(ary) {

    this.mtx = ary
    this.height = ary.length;
    this.width = ary[0].length;
}

Matrix.prototype.toString = function() {
    var s = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.mtx.length; i++) 
        s.push( this.mtx[i].join(",") );
    return s.join("\n");
}

// returns a new matrix
Matrix.prototype.transpose = function() {
    var transposed = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        transposed[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
            transposed[i][j] = this.mtx[j][i];
        }
    }
    return new Matrix(transposed);
}
```

I am aware that I may be approaching this all wrong.   And I'm aware that the questions I have are very basic, I'm a little embarrassed to ask these simple questions.   Please excuse me.   I'm  43 years old and had c programming in college 20 years ago.  I'm pretty good with HTML and CSS but I'm lacking in a lot of areas.   Hope someone can help me with this.   Thanks.

Comment: What does the `Tr` function do? Also, I don't see you creating any array there on which you could apply `Matrix` - you seem to deal only with strings.

Comment: the Tr functions adds a line break or spaces in the text area (i think)...this is where it breaks the text up into rows of X and/or groups of X number of charters.  I'm not sure how to feed this into an array.   Maybe you can advise me.  Like i said i'm a beginner.   I've seen this clip on stackoverflow but again, not sure how to change it, add it, or  of if it's what i'm looking for.:     var lines = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value.split('\\n');

Comment: Two good tutorials: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html, http://javascript.info/tutorial/array. And yes, the `split` function is likely what you want.

Comment: for example i can have group of 5 characters with 5 groups on 1 row.  That would be 5 groups of 5 in a row  with spaces in between each group and then a line break after the 5th group of 5.   Or i could have 1 group of five with a line break after the 5th character which would result if five rows and five columns.